# TypeScritp generic composed types definition

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm wondering is there any functional difference between following TypeScript types declarations:
`object: Observable<number> | Observable<number[]>`
`object: Observable<number | number[]>`
If so, what are they, If no, then what's preferred way of defining such?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the second one. Consider the following example (not with observables, but with simple Set objects)

```
const something: Set<number> | Set<number[]> = new Set();
const something2: Set<number | number[]> = new Set();

something.add(2);  // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((value: number) => Set<number>) | ((value: number[]) => Set<number[]>)' has no compatible call signatures.
something.add([2, 3, 4]); // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((value: number) => Set<number>) | ((value: number[]) => Set<number[]>)' has no compatible call signatures.

something2.add(2);
something2.add([2, 3, 4]);
```

As you can see, the fist one can only work if you cast the *something* object that will be an unneccessary noise in your code in this case:

```
(something as Set<number>).add(2);
(something as Set<number[]>).add([2, 3, 4]);
```